# why webform (asp.net-3.5)appears excluded after copying it to local system from the production server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web

I have jsut copied one web apllication (web project) developed in asp.net 3.5 with c# and working fine now, from the live server to my local host. My question is The form which is avialble in live server is not avialble when executed from local host. then i found that form was excluded from project, viewed in solution explorer. i got erros after including that form in project and compiled, those errors are

> Error 1 :frmUpdateNCR.aspx.cs 'EAudit.AUDIT_BAL.AuditRoleSubmit' does
>   not contain a definition for 'Afpf_Editedby' and no extension method
>   'Afpf_Editedby' accepting a first argument of type
>   'EAudit.AUDIT_BAL.AuditRoleSubmit' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)    142 26  EAudit
>
> Error 2:frmUpdateNCR.aspx.cs  'EAudit.AUDIT_BAL.AuditRoleSubmit' does
>   not contain a definition for 'UpdateNCRAfterEditing' and no extension
>   method 'UpdateNCRAfterEditing' accepting a first argument of type
>   'EAudit.AUDIT_BAL.AuditRoleSubmit' could be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly reference?)    146 35  EAudit.

The parameter and function are already added in class file when uploaded into production server but same are not available in the applicaiton which is in local host.

I am sure i copied correct file but i dont know why this happened, could any one give me solution. sorry if this question is not to be here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're copying it down from the production server it's probably been compiled. If you can't find the `[webform].aspx.cs` or `[webform].aspx.designer.cs` file, then the code has been compiled into a DLL in the BIN folder, and you won't be able to include it in your project.

If there is a code file, then go to the solution explorer and click the "Show All Files" icon at the top. Find the web form (should be greyed out if it's excluded), right click on it and then click "Include In Project", and you should be all set.